# Performance of one function vs. multiple

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have many drag and drop objects on the stage, and the default code snippet adds a new event listener and function to the stage for each object:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void { instance_1.stopDrag(); }
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_1);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop_1(event:MouseEvent):void { instance_2.stopDrag(); }
....
```

Would it be better or worse to put them all into one listener?

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void {
  instance_1.stopDrag();
  instance_2.stopDrag();
  ....
}
```

Comment: Where is your `startDrag` happening?

Comment: If you worry about performance then you should start by finding a way to not trigger all those stopDrag() for all your instances. Surely they can't be all dragged at the same time so the right thing to do first would be to make sure only the instance being dragged is stopped.

Comment: Start drag is in main stage, single frame, action layer. Just learning AS3 after being out of practice for a few years. And I want to be able to drag each item individually. With AS2 I could put the code in the object, so start/stop was specific to the object. No longer with AS3, hence the question.

Comment: You need to think harder. How many function calls should you have ideally? stage listener is 1, then stopDrag is another so total is 2. Ideally you should have 2 method calls top. In your first code example for let's say 10 instances you get 20 calls, in the second code for lets' say 10 instances you get 11 calls. Better but not quite there.

Comment: Yes in sa2 you could put the code inside the object so if you had to handle 350 objects you would put the same code inside 350 objects, now was that really a good way to code? Surely not. In as2 too you could write OOP or at the least write reusable code by using methods or prototype. As2 is not an excuse for writing bad code.

Comment: @Naidim I updated my answer with a possible solution based on what you've described.

Comment: @BotMaster: I see what you're saying, and preferably there would be a single reusable function. I just don't know how to do it in AS. Something like: instance_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag(this [or would it be instance_1?]); function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent, object_ref):void { object_ref.startDrag(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One function call is surely faster than multiple function calls. However, the difference here is going to be negligible.

From a code readability stand-point, I would say the single function call you've shown is better.

---

Generally, the way I like to do drag-and-drop is to add the `mouseUp` handler when I start the drag, and remove it immediately when dragging is completed. For example:

```
instance1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
instance2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
instance3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);

function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Sprite(e.currentTarget).startDrag();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}

function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopDrag();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sprite(e.currentTarget) was exactly what I was looking for to create a reusable function.

Comment: this is not the best solution and the "stopDrag();" alone in the mouseUp is not gonna do much.

Comment: @BotMaster Well, it won't do much besides stop the drag. ;) You don't need to call `stopDrag` on the same sprite that you called `startDrag` on.

Comment: not being explicit on coding is always a dangerous game. Still recommend calling it on the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

For a Flash timeline easy and efficient solution you simply keep reference to your object and that's about it:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
instance1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
instance2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
instance3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
var draggedObject:Sprite;

function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    draggedObject = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
    if(draggedObject)
    {
        draggedObject.startDrag();
    }        
}

function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(draggedObject)
    {
        draggedObject.stopDrag();
        draggedObject = null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This won't compile: `startDrag` is defined on `Sprite`, not `DisplayObject`.

Comment: that's what happen when I write code out of the top of my head. edited.

Comment: Great start. But what if you need to pass variables to the mouseUp to accurately snap objects in position? e.g. if (sprite.x > 100 and sprite x < 200) sprite.x = 150. And those values are different for EVERY sprite. All the "Pass Parameter" examples I've seen have predefined the function call as a variable, but then how would you do it for different sprites? One for each? That would be far more code than a single mouseUp() that performs on every sprite.

Comment: Don't get me started on that! ;) I only use classes and OOP so very easy I create a custom class that accept low and high limit and automatically snap back into place when passing the limits. 5 minutes of work top. Now doing this on timeline ... I don't really want to think about it honestly.